# How to know if my code is energy efficient?

Tags: optimization, code-analysis, energy

With everything becoming Software driven, its important to ensure the code we write is energy efficient? Are there any IDE plugins, tools, guidelines to know how optimized is the code? Something like SonarLint...

Comment: Benchmark it. Less runtime means less energy.

Comment: Oh my god the wit, how are you so smart? Please...

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

For code, efficient and energy-efficient are really the same thing. Just use any profiler to identify what is using the most cpu und memory in your code and optimize those things.